# Event grid custom topic(with private end point) and event source as blob storage and event handler as storage queue

Tags: azure, azure-eventgrid

If I use storage account as event topic (custom), it automatically expects for an existing system topic during a event subscription creation fyi. which means we cannot create a custom topic with storage account if the topic type is storage account.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rvom6.png)

our request is to

Create a event grid topic with private endpoint
Create event subscription for that topic
the event handler should be either Storage queue or Webhook?
Source: blob storage
Destination: queue storage (to store events)
What would be your best advise here?
Also, If I prefer a webhook as event handler, what would be the best practice to trigger a webhook? Thank you,

I'm trying to setup an event grid custom topic with a private endpoint for blob storage for events like (blob created and blob deleted) and event handler as storage queue. For some reason I don't know the events are not getting generated in the queue. I tried without private end point as well. But when I go to the events section in the storage account and create a system topic (type: storage account) and a subscription, it generates the events successfully.
If the event topic is custom (type: event grid topic), then the expected outcome is not working. I also see system topic don't support private endpoint

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. I suggest editing the title of your question to be in the form of a question (?) so people would be interested in reading more about your problem. I'm not familiar with this topic but hopefully getting more people to look at your question would increase the chances of getting answers.

Answer (score 0):

> If I use storage account as event topic (custom), it automatically
> expects for an existing system topic during a event subscription
> creation fyi. which means we cannot create a custom topic with storage
> account if the topic type is storage account.

**yes, you are absolutely right**. It expects for existing system topic so you can't create custom topic with storage account.

> Create a event grid topic with private endpoint Create event
> subscription for that topic the event handler should be either Storage
> queue or Webhook?

- As per your requirement by Following this MS [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/configure-private-endpoints)Created Custom event grid private endpoint. Here my topic type is Event Grid Topic in Create Event Subscription.
- Then Go to Created Event Grid Custom topic >> Entities >>  Event Subscriptions >> + Event Subscription.
- As shown in below image when creating event subscription, **you can choose Endpoint type as Storage Queue/Web Hook.**
  [image]
- Here i am selecting Storage Queues as Endpoint Type and then click on select an endpoint then in this page you can select your storage a/c and queue and click on select as shown in image.
  [image]
  You can also take Webhook as endpoint by following this MS [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/subscribe-through-portal).
- I am just suggesting that if you are facing any issues with storage/webhook you can also Connect to private endpoints with [Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/azure-functions-private-endpoints/connect-to-private-endpoints-with-azure-functions/).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Doen't synapse create it's own webhook subscription when you reference custom topic?
The open question is if this is true, then how can Synapse create a subscription where the webhook endpoint is not a public url? Because we use PE for the custom topic